# Jquery Autocomplete returns no suggestions when I type

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to figure out why jQuery autocomplete isn't giving me any results from the drop down menu as I type. I'm calling an asp.net controller, everything is returning fine when I loop through the results within the $.each method in the console. What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 3,
    source: function (request, patients) {

        $.get("patient/Search/", { search: request.term }, function (patients) {

            $.each(patients, function (key, value) {
                patients[key].PatientFullName;
                console.log(patients[key].PatientFullName);

            });
        });


    },

    open: function(event, patients) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);

    },
    select: function (event, patients) {
        $.each(patients, function (key, value) {

            //window.location.href = "/patient/" + patients[key].PatientID;
        });

    }
});
```

Here is the json being returned from the asp.net controller

```
[{"PatientID":"bcf81edb-bbfe-42d1-afcf-3255ca78fb32","PatientFullName":"Smith, Shane","PatientNameAndDOB":"Smith, Shane(5-05-13)","PatientNameAgeGender":"Smith, Shane (16 month old M)","Photo":null},{"PatientID":"26fd757d-4b92-471e-9396-3c9d69f54a32","PatientFullName":"Smith, Shirley","PatientNameAndDOB":"Smith, Shirley(5-05-13)","PatientNameAgeGender":"Smith, Shirley (16 month old F)","Photo":null}]
```

Comment: What's showing in your console?

Comment: This is the console results
Smith, Shane
Smith, Shirley 


The Network/XHR Response tab in Chrome
[{"PatientID":"bcf81edb-bbfe-42d1-afcf-3255ca78fb32","PatientFullName":"Smith, Shane","PatientNameAndDOB":"Smith, Shane(5-05-13)","PatientNameAgeGender":"Smith, Shane (16 month old M)","Photo":null},{"PatientID":"26fd757d-4b92-471e-9396-3c9d69f54a32","PatientFullName":"Smith, Shirley","PatientNameAndDOB":"Smith, Shirley(5-05-13)","PatientNameAgeGender":"Smith, Shirley (16 month old F)","Photo":null}]

Answer (score 0):

Per the jQuery autocomplete [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

> Function: The third variation, a callback, provides the most
> flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to
> Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments: A request object, with
> a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the
> text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field,
> the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo". **A response callback, which**
> **expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data**
> **should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of**
> **the formats described above for simple local data**. It's important when
> providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the
> request. You must always call the response callback even if you
> encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the
> correct state. When filtering data locally, you can make use of the
> built-in $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex function. It'll take a single
> string argument and escape all regex characters, making the result
> safe to pass to new RegExp().

Type of data supported:

String - Which is basically a string for a URL to call that will return JSON that once again: **The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.**

Which brings us to:

Array:

> An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
>
> An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

So basically, why you aren't seeing any results is because the JSON you are returning does not match either of the specified patterns for the array.  As well as the fact that you have some issues with your JS.

Assuming you returned JSON similar to this

```
[
     {
          value:"bcf81edb-bbfe-42d1-afcf-3255ca78fb32",
          label:"Smith, Shane"
     },
     {
          value:"26fd757d-4b92-471e-9396-3c9d69f54a32",
          label:"Smith, Shirley"
     }
]
```

Then you could have JS like this:

```
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 3,
        source: "home/search",
        open: function (event, patients) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);

        },
        select: function (event, patients) {
            $.each(patients, function (key, value) {
            });
        }
    });
```

If you needed to massage the data on the client side for whatever reason, then you could do something like this:

```
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 3,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.get("home/search", { search: request.term }, function (patients) {
                var finalResult;
                //do something to massage the patients data into finalResult
                finalResult = doWork;
                response(finalResult);
            });
        },
        open: function (event, patients) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);

        },
        select: function (event, patients) {
            $.each(patients, function (key, value) {
            });
        }
    });
```